# ListView Adapter How to skip data

Tags: java, android, android-listview

i have a Adapter that  extends BaseAdapter, i had mapped Items sucessfully but i wanted if the filename ends with ".php" it didn't show any data.
i am using following code for this

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row=convertView;
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, parent, false);
    if(data.get(position).name.endsWith(".php"))
    row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

But this will leave that blank space in that listview.

Is there any way i made check on listView that it didn't mapped that data which name ends with ".php", don't want blank screen at this point.

Comment: instead of doing this try eliminating the values from the object which you are using here to get the name (data.get(position))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already extending `BaseAdapter`, in whichever methods you add items, go through them first and don't add the ones that you don't want.

Comment: This is an array list of data that i am mapping on listView, and that data is fetching from online server.

Comment: Exactly, make a copy of the ArrayList in your adapter and remove the items that you want.

Comment: O yes Clever...very Clever :) Let me try this, I think u got it right